# iOS 13.5.1: UIActivityViewController not showing on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios13, uiactivityviewcontroller

The following code works fine on an iPhone on iOS 13.5.1 and an iPad on iOS 12.4.7, but nothing happens when it's triggered on an iPad on iOS 13.5.1:

```c
- (void)notificationFired:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (notification != (id)[NSNull null] && [[notification name] isEqualToString:@"OpenActionSheet"]) {
        NSString *path = [notification userInfo][@"path"];
        
        printf("Received path: %s", path.UTF8String);

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        
        UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[url] applicationActivities:nil];
        [controller setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
            printf("%s", "Share sheet closed");
            UnitySendMessage("ShareListener", "Complete", path.UTF8String);
        }];
        
        if (IDIOM == IPAD)
            controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover

        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
        
        if (IDIOM == IPAD) {
            UIPopoverPresentationController *popover = controller.popoverPresentationController;
            popover.sourceView = self.window.rootViewController.view;
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried

```c
if ([controller respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)])
    controller.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.rootView;
        
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead of the `IDIOM == IPAD` blocks, but that has the same results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just assigning `sourceView`, you should also assigning `sourceRect`

Like

```
popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) // change the rect to the frame you want the view to appear
```

I hope it'll fix your problem. Tested in iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) XCode 11.5.